# how do you check for nulls in any column in an entire table in SQL

Tags: sql, null

I would like to check if any of my columns in a table have any null values. I am sure there is a quicker way than how I am doing it at the moment. I just want to see if there is a NULL in ANY column however my table has a lot of columns, is there a simple and quick way?

This way I have written so far works but it takes a long time to do for every column (hence the etc etc)

```
  select 
sum(case when id is null then 1 else 0 end) as id, 
sum(case when name is null then 1 else 0 end) as name, 
sum(case when review_count is null then 1 else 0 end) as review_coun,
sum(case when positive_review is null then 1 else 0 end) as 
positive_review, 
sum(etc etc
from user
```

Comment: While ISO standard SQL does have reflection capabilities (via `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`) it does not have built-in support for iterating over columns or other named objects - for that you need to use Dynamic-SQL, unfortunately - which varies depending on your RDBMS. What system are you using?

Comment: You can still get rid of those `case`s by using just `COUNT(*) - COUNT(id)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work for your scenario, but it's an option.  You can `CAST` all your columns as a string and then concatenate them together.  If you concatenate a `NULL` value with a string, it will return `NULL`.

```
SELECT 'Y' 
WHERE EXISTS( -- Check if there are any NULL rows
  SELECT 
    CAST(c1 AS CHAR(1)) || 
    CAST(c2 AS CHAR(1)) || 
    ... 
    AS MyColumns
  WHERE MyColumns IS NULL
)
;
```